# MySQL Docker image keeps shutting down

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build two docker images for the two components of by project. One is a node application and the other is the MySQL DB. I am using a script to create the databases and fill up the tables in the DB docker image because I couldn't create stored procedures using the ORM. My configuration for it is like this:

```
FROM mysql:8.0.26
ADD initialization.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ENV MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=thisisfine
EXPOSE 3306
```

When I run docker-compose up --build, the database image shuts down which causes issues with my other image. I am unable to figure out why. This is what is present in the logs:

```
Creating libraryly_db_1 ... done                                                                                                                           
Creating libraryly_backend_1 ... done                                                                                                                      
Attaching to libraryly_db_1, libraryly_backend_1                                                                                                           
backend_1  | Waiting for the DB to start...                                                                                                                
db_1       | 2021-08-15 17:10:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.                                   
db_1       | 2021-08-15 17:10:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'                                                            
db_1       | 2021-08-15 17:10:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.                                   
db_1       | 2021-08-15 17:10:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files                                                                    
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:10:58.655968Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) initializing of server in progress as process 42 
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:10:58.676504Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.                                                
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:10:59.618507Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.                                                  
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:01.811035Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main                 
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:01.811791Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main               
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:02.140665Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off 
the --initialize-insecure option.                                                                                                                          
db_1       | 2021-08-15 17:11:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized                                                                     
db_1       | 2021-08-15 17:11:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server                                                                      
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:07.714680Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) starting as process 91                           
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:07.750557Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.                                                
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:08.000431Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.                                                  
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:08.397505Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main                 
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:08.397776Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main               
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:08.399964Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.                                            
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:08.400702Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now suppor
ted for this channel.                                                                                                                                      
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:08.407431Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is 
accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.                                                                                       
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:08.463387Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock               
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:08.463648Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.26'  socket: '/var/run/mysq
ld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.                                                                                                    
db_1       | 2021-08-15 17:11:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.                                                                      
db_1       | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.                                                          
db_1       | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.                                                    
db_1       | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.                                                             
db_1       | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.                                                         
backend_1  | Operation timed out                                                                                                                           
backend_1  | Starting the server...                                                                                                                        
db_1       |                                                                                                                                               
db_1       | 2021-08-15 17:11:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initialization.sql    
backend_1  |                                                                                                                                               
backend_1  | > libraryly@1.0.0 start /app                                                                                                                  
backend_1  | > node app                                                                                                                                    
backend_1  |                                                                                                                                               
db_1       |                                                                                                                                               
db_1       |                                                                                                                                               
db_1       | 2021-08-15 17:11:16+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server                                                                      
db_1       | 2021-08-15T17:11:16.132929Z 11 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.26).        
backend_1  | Listening at: http://localhost:5000                                                                                                           
backend_1  | ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.23.0.2:3306                                                
backend_1  |     at ConnectionManager.connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:116:17)                                
backend_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)                                                                       
backend_1  |     at async ConnectionManager._connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:318:24)                      
backend_1  |     at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:250:32                                                   
backend_1  |     at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:280:7)                  
backend_1  |     at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:613:26                                                                              
backend_1  |     at async Sequelize.authenticate (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:867:5) {                                                    
backend_1  |   parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.23.0.2:3306                                                                                         
backend_1  |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {                                                                       
backend_1  |     errno: -111,                                                                                                                              
backend_1  |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',                                                                                                                     
backend_1  |     syscall: 'connect',                                                                                                                       
backend_1  |     address: '172.23.0.2',                                                                                                                    
backend_1  |     port: 3306,                                                                                                                               
backend_1  |     fatal: true
```

I can't figure out what is causing the root user to send a shutdown request. Please help.

Comment: The standard Docker Hub database images run in two phases.  In the first phase the database isn't network-accessible, but the initialization scripts run; in the second phase the database is fully functioning.  This looks like you're seeing the shutdown scripts from the first phase but the application isn't waiting long enough for the second phase to start up.  If you run `docker-compose up -d` twice, waiting maybe 30 seconds, does it start successfully the second time?

Answer (score 0):

in this case You don't need a dockerfile if you're using docker-compose, you can configure your docker-compose file like this

```
version: "3.7"

services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql:8.0.17
     container_name: localmysql
     command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
       MYSQL_DATABASE: initialDatabaseName
     ports:
       - 3306:3306
     volumes:
       - /your_local/path:/var/lib/mysql
```

if you want to initialize your db I recommend you to use an ORM what allow you to use database migrations, or run your script from your backend